# Substituting a binomial into the infinite geometric series formula

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials, power-series

In this case, regarding series $\frac1{2+x}$:

Can you use $(1-x)$ as the common ratio instead of factoring out a $\frac12$ and using $-\frac{x}2$ [as the common ratio].

WolframAlpha says that $\sum_{n=o}^{\infty}(-1-x)^n$ (from $\frac1{1-(-1-x)}$) ≠ $\frac12\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\frac{-x}2)^n$ (from $\frac{\frac12}{1-\frac{-x}2}$).

EDIT: Why can't you use $(1-x)$?

Comment: btw where is the binomial ?

Comment: $(1-x)$ is a binomial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Newton's [negative](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NegativeBinomialSeries.html) [binomial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinomialTheorem.html) series more generally $$(1+z)^n=\sum_{0\le r<\infty}\frac{n(n-1)\cdots (n-r+1)}{r!}z^r\text{  for } |z|<1$$

$$(1-a)^{-1}=\sum_{0\le r<\infty}\frac{(-1)(-1-1)\cdots (-1-r+1)}{r!}(-a)^r$$
$$=\sum_{0\le r<\infty}\frac{(-1)^r 1\cdot2\cdots (r-1)r}{r!}(-a)^r$$
$$=\sum_{0\le r<\infty}\frac{r!}{r!}a^r=\sum_{0\le r<\infty}a^r$$

Answer (score 0):

Yeah these are two different things, as 
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left( \frac{-x}{2} \right)^n $$ 
has a radius of convergence of 2 and 
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1-x)^n $$ 
has only a radius of convergence of 1.
You can easily test it if you chose $x=0$ than the first is $\frac{1}{2}$, the second diverges.

Comment: Why are they different if $\frac{\frac12}{1-\frac{-x}2} = \frac1{1-(-1-x)}$

Comment: @Andrew it's only the same when both series converge